# How to create a new collection of objects using the contents of two other collections without a nested loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, nested-loops

I need to create a collection of objects using the contents of an array of Guids and a collection of strings.  It's easy enough to do using nested loops such as

```js
Guid[] guids;
string[] names;
NewObject[] combined;

foreach(Guid g in guids) {
    foreach(string name in names) {
      combined.Add(new NewObject() {
          Guid = g, Name = name
      }
    }
  }
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a way that I could do this without the nested loop.  I've been wracking my brain to try to figure out a way, but can't come up with one.

Comment: Do the arrays have always the same length?

Comment: The code you posted produces every combination of the guids with the strings, so if you had 4 guids and 5 strings the final collection would have 20 elements. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Abdelkrim:  Unfortunately, the arrays are of different lengths
Matthew:  Yes, every combination of the Guid array and the string array

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0):

```
Guid[] guids;
string[] names;
NewObject[] combined;

var combinedObjects = Enumerable.Zip<Guid, string, NewObject>(guids, names, (guid, name) => new NewObject {Guid = guid, Name = name});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, arrays should be of the same size. and then you can run a single `for` loop to set the object, there is no need for two `for` loops.

```
NewObject[] combined = new NewObject[guids.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++)
{
    combined[i] = new NewObject { Guid = guids[i], Name = names[i] };
}
```